# Filtering string in java

Tags: java, arrays, string, substring

It's not about filtering bad words so get in. Imagine that you have list of strings named as
abcd,abcde,abcdef,abfg,abdc if a user gives string abc as filter in ConsoleProgram abcd,abcde and abcdef will be printed out. I thought about using substring but I couldn't achieved it does anybody have any idea .. 
note that I am new to java and not competent thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first thing you need is learn about String Regex, maybe here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/.
Try out the next simply code.

```
public class StringMatcher {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] words = new String[]{"abcd", "abcde", "abcdef", "abfg", "abdc"};
        String filter = "abc";

        for (String word : words) {
            if (word.matches(filter + "(.*)")) {
                System.out.println("This pass the filter: " + word);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The best thanks.. One more detail,How would I make it work as a Java applet? Is it possible to type abc there and then printed the expected outputs under there

Comment: @regeme I dont think here we must have to use regex. String#contains(string) is best for this case.

Comment: You need four components (A TextField where type the list, a second textfield where insert the filter, a Button which one you use to process the method and a Label where you have to show the results). For me Java Applet is an old fashion way to solve a problem by the way, the logic is the same, you need an ActionListener for the button and call the method that could process it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this: If the item in list contains the string inputted by user it will get printed.

```
input = "abc";
for(int i = 0 ; i < list.size(); i++){
  if (list.get(i).contains(input))
    System.out.println(list.get(i));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's say your Strings are in an ArrayList called wordBank.

```
for(String i : wordBank) { //loops through the array with 'i' being current index
    if(i.contains("abc")) { //checks if index contains filter String
        System.out.println(i); //prints out index if filter String is present
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use `String.contains()` - it returns true when string contains given char sequence, see [string-javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html)

Comment: In its current form this should be a comment